# Separate View Controllers for every view vs Nested views in a single View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

When designing your application structure:

It is better to put nested`UIView` in a single `UIViewController` and navigate from one to another programmatically OR create for every`UIView`
a `UIViewController`, and why ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to know which structure is better when building your application
Separate ViewController for every View and using the NavigationController to navigate between them OR put nested view inside each others in a single ViewController then show and hide them when needed?

Comment: UIViews are fine for dumb data or data with limited logic. When the logic starts getting complicated, it's time to make a UIViewController. Unfortunately, you can only get an instinct for the threshold for 'complicated' by getting it wrong a bunch of times.

Answer (score 0):

When building the structure for your application, I suggest using the UIViewController per UIView method you outlined in your comments. This method is commonly known as MVC or Model - View - Controller. MVC can be explained with this example: if a user is looking at picture on your application and decides to swipe left on that picture, the UIView containing that picture (View) will register that interaction and send it to the UIViewController (Controller). The UIViewController then will update your  data source of pictures (Model) saying that it needs the next picture. The Model then updates the UIViewController with the next picture. The UIViewController then updates the UIView with the next picture and the UIView now displays this next picture. Hope that example helps.

This is explained fully here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html